# Identify community in a direct graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, social-networks, network-analysis

I'm trying to identify communities in a direct graph.

I only know how to use Spectral clustering and Girvan-Newman method but the both the methods work only with undirect graph. Am I wrong?

So what method could I use to solve the following problem?

The text of the problem is the following:

> **Trawling** - Identify the communities of the following webgraph with a minimum support of two and a minimum itemset size of two. Plot the resulting bipartite graphs.
>
> [image]

What I tried to do was  using Spectral Clustering: I transcribed the graph but what I obtained was a squared non-symmetric Adjacency matrix (**A**).

When there is an arrow from 1 to 2  the value **a12** in the matrix is **1** instead the value **a21** is 0.

Now I've problems calculating the Degree Matrix (**D**). All its values are 0 except for the ones along the main diagonal that are the sum of the values in their rows. Is it correct?

Finally I calculate the Laplacian Matrix (**L**) computing: L=D-A

Now I'm stuck I don't know how to go on, how do I calculate Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors?

Comment: Can you explain what are the *support* and *itemset size*? The question that you are asking is clearly community detection in directed graphs, for which there are some algorithms, but the problem that you are trying to solve **Trawling** is not clearly defined.

Comment: Don't use the sophisticated algorithms. Instead, use the definitions in the question to find out (using brute force) the communities per the definition in the question.